# Subsetting dataframe based on unique values and other column data

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe that has a series of ID characters (trt,individual, and session):

```
> trt<-c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3),rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3),rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3))
individual<-rep(c("Bob","Nancy","Tim"),9)
session<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9)
data<-rnorm(27,mean=4,sd=1)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(trt,individual,session,data))
df
   trt individual session             data
1    A        Bob       1 4.36604594311893
2    A      Nancy       1 3.29568979189961
3    A        Tim       1 3.55849387209243
4    B        Bob       2 5.41661201729216
5    B      Nancy       2  4.7158873476798
6    B        Tim       2 5.34401708530548
7    C        Bob       3 4.54277206331273
8    C      Nancy       3 3.53976115781019
9    C        Tim       3  3.7954788384957
10   A        Bob       4 4.75145309337952
11   A      Nancy       4  4.7995601464568
12   A        Tim       4 3.17821205815185
13   B        Bob       5 3.62379779744325
14   B      Nancy       5 4.07387328854209
15   B        Tim       5 5.60156909861945
16   C        Bob       6 4.06727142161431
17   C      Nancy       6 4.59940289933985
18   C        Tim       6 3.07543217234973
19   A        Bob       7 2.63468285023662
20   A      Nancy       7 3.22650587327078
21   A        Tim       7 6.31062631711196
22   B        Bob       8 4.69047076193906
23   B      Nancy       8 4.79190101388308
24   B        Tim       8 1.61906440409175
25   C        Bob       9 2.85180524036416
26   C      Nancy       9 3.43304058627408
27   C        Tim       9 4.89263600498695
```

I am looking to create a new dataframe where I have randomly pulled each trtxindividual combination but under the constraint that each unique session number is only selected once

This is what I want my dataframe to look like:

```
    trt individual session             data
2    A      Nancy       1 3.29568979189961
4    B        Bob       2 5.41661201729216
9    C        Tim       3  3.7954788384957
10   A        Bob       4 4.75145309337952
15   B        Tim       5 5.60156909861945
17   C      Nancy       6 4.59940289933985
21   A        Tim       7 6.31062631711196
23   B      Nancy       8 4.79190101388308
25   C        Bob       9 2.85180524036416
```

I know how to randomly select a subset of each trtxindividual combination:

```
> setDT(df)
newdf<-df[, .SD[sample(.N, 1)] , by=.(trt, individual)]
newdf
  trt individual session             data
1:   A        Bob       4 4.75145309337952
2:   A      Nancy       1 3.29568979189961
3:   A        Tim       7 6.31062631711196
4:   B        Bob       8 4.69047076193906
5:   B      Nancy       **2**  4.7158873476798
6:   B        Tim       **2** 5.34401708530548
7:   C        Bob       6 4.06727142161431
8:   C      Nancy       9 3.43304058627408
9:   C        Tim       3  3.7954788384957
```

But I dont know how to restrict the pulls to only allow one session to be pulled (aka not allow duplicates as there are above)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think `df<-as.data.frame(cbind(trt,individual,session,data))` is better to avoid getting classes in the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will need to iterate through the `data.table` and might not be quick, but it doesn't require setting any parameters for the fields of interest

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(7)

setDT(df)
dt1 <- df[, .SD[sample(.N)]]
dt1[, i := .I]
dt1[, flag := NA]
setkey(dt1, flag)

lapply(dt1$i, function(x) {
  dt1[is.na(flag[x]) & (trt == trt[x] & individual == individual[x] | session == session[x]), flag := i == x]
})

dt1[flag == TRUE, ]

   trt individual session             data  i flag
1:   C        Tim       9 3.63712332100071  1 TRUE
2:   A      Nancy       4 4.54908662150973  2 TRUE
3:   A        Tim       1 5.84217708521442  3 TRUE
4:   B        Tim       2 2.37343483362789  5 TRUE
5:   C      Nancy       3 2.87792051390258  7 TRUE
6:   A        Bob       7 3.45471592963754 12 TRUE
7:   B      Nancy       8 4.54792567807183 15 TRUE
8:   C        Bob       6 4.45667777212948 24 TRUE
9:   B        Bob       5 2.33285598638319 27 TRUE
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!! I am trying to understand what the lapply function is doing. You randomize the dataframe with df[,.SD[sample(.N)]]. Then run the function in lapply that takes the first unique trt x individual combination x session, then as it runs through the datatable it recognizes the different trt x individual combinations with the same session number and calls these false?

Comment: That is correct, `lapply` is iterating through the `data.table` then after finding the first unique combination it will set that flag to `TRUE` and then remove invalid future choices from consideration by setting flag to `FALSE`.

Comment: I have added an additional question (part 2) as an edit to my original as I thought it may require a new answer. If you have any ideas on how to do this I appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: @broch this should be asked a new question as it is substantially different from the original question.  Also, have you tried anything?  This site is supportive of effort and helping fix errors, but not code this for me.

Comment: I will make a new question. I have tried many things, I will put some of these in my question to show effort.